# block access to file while using opendir/openfile etc

Tags: php, file, .htaccess, block, chmod

i want to deny access to file data.xml for functions like file_exists/opendir/openfile etc

my file test.php contains:

```
$path="./mydata.html";
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {

}

closedir($handle);
```

how to make it unreadable without blocking functions? is it possible?

- .htaccess?
- should i block file via chmod set by different user than i execute php script?
- other way?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to write a function to check the filepath, and call (i.e.) `sanitize_filepath($path)` whenever you accept user data or before every `fopen()`/`opendir()`/`file_get_contents()`.  In the `sanitize_filepath()` function, explode `$path` on `PATH_SEPARATOR` and use `in_array()` to check your internal blacklist against your provided path.

Return false or throw an Exception if you don't watch to continue, the filepath or true if you do.

Preventing access via .htaccess just means that I cannot go to http://example.com/your/website/data.xml and see the file.  I could still potentially access the file by exploiting your PHP script if I requested http://example.com/your/website/script.php?file=data.xml, assuming script.php was `<?= echo file_get_contents($_GET['file']); ?>`.  (This is obviously a useless and insecure script, but it's an example.)

Preventing access via chmodding the permissions could prevent PHP from reading the file.  If you don't need to read the file, it shouldn't be in a place that PHP can access it-- move it outside of your webroot.